# Scramble the file names generated by php script for my amazon s3 files?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Hello everyone I was wondering if there's a way to have a random text generated and replaces my file names (and of course still have the link work) ?

I've noticed how people like to have files (mostly video) have very random characters as file names instead of a relevant file names. Are they generated as each user view the page? Or is it really a file with a name of random characters? I cannot imagine this can be efficient if you have large amounts of files.

I'm currently using the script from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/generate-expiring-amazon-s3-link/

This allows me to not share my files publicly but the users cannot access the file directly. I hope that makes sense, let me know what you think.

Thank you

Comment: You could use hashing to achieve this effect; display file hashes as the file name, then pass the hash as a parameter to a server side script that matches the hash to the file. Not sure about the specifics of such a scheme with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you could probably use [S3 Website Redirects](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/10/amazon-s3-support-for-website-redirects.html) to accomplish this.

Simply create a random new file with the correct HTTP header set, and have it redirect back to the real file. This uses an HTTP 301 redirect, so loading it in a web browser or requesting it with cURL or wget will end up resolving the real location.